# How can I add Codeigniter datatable action button based on the database status?

Tags: database, codeigniter, if-statement, button, datatables

I want to show action button based on my database status result value.

If the database status value is `1` then datatable action button should be `lock icon`.

Else if the database status value is `0`, then datatable action button should be `unlock icon`.

Comment: have your problem is solved or not.

Comment: I found a solution. Thank you

Comment: but if my answer helps you then please marked as accepted answers for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$status=$dataRow['status'];

if($status==1)
{
    $statusValue="lock icon";
}
elseif($status==0)
{
    $statusValue="unlock icon";
}
 echo "<button>'.$statusValue.'</button>";  

?>
```

**Note:-** For More Reference see Control Statements in PHP.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php